# AWS credential file - Can I have more than one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I use a VPC connection to an RDS mySql DB... the credentials I use I cannot reuse to connect to an S3 bucket.  I have keys and token but I cannot add to that credential file.  Is is stored in my SSH folder and I cannot edit it.
Is there a way to have more than one credential file one for RDS and one for S3?

Comment: Yes, you can create different profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use named profiles. configure additional profiles by using
`aws configure` with the `--profile` option

or add access key and secret in  ~/.aws/credentials (Linux & Mac) or %USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials (Windows) files as below

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

[user1]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
```

Use as below

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile user1
```

follow the below link for more details. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html